# how can I flip from camera to screen recording

Tags: video, screen-capture

I just get my new canon 70d camera. I want to use it for recording online tutorial and publish it in YouTube. how can I flip from camera to screen recording and vise verse while recording? are there some programs for doing that?

Comment: Your best approach is to record both in parallel throughout the tutorial, then use a video editor to switch between the two video tracks at the appropriate points. The video editor can then publish with the resolution and compression parameters that you want to use for your YouTube production.

Comment: @AFH are there any app helping you to do that while you are recording? it will save much time

Comment: Not that I'm aware of. It may take longer to use a video editor, but you will get a much better-finished video, making the transitions at just the right point, and you can edit out imperfections, such as intrusions and hesitations in the audio, jerky camera movements, etc.